# Make generator with recursion and promises play nicely

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6, generator

It's possible to make a "Scrolling" request to Elasticsearch. It keeps a cursor open and you can retrieve large chunks of data piece by piece.

[There's some demo code available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-scroll), that uses callbacks and recursion to keep fetching data until we're finished. In the Node app I'm writing, I want to stream every chunk of data into a zip or write it somewhere, and then forget about it and fetch a new chunk of data. However in the example they store all the data into an array which can cause memory issues for large amounts of data.

**A generator function would be perfect to fetch some data from Elasticsearch on every `.next()`, then write it away before calling another `.next()` that will get some data from the scroll endpoint and use recursion.**

I'm currently really confused how this can be achieved. We have to synchronously wait for the promise (Elasticsearch call) to resolve, then yield the response. But it also needs to yield a recursive function, etc.

After trying for hours with different ways, the mix of generator functions, promises, and recursion has confused me. I wrote some simplified code that resembles what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
console.clear();

// Elasticsearch search call
function searchMockPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let response = {};
            response.hits = {
                total: 50,
                hits: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            };
            resolve(response);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

// Elasticsearch scroll call
function scrollMockPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let response = {};
            response.hits = {
                total: 50,
                hits: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            };
            resolve(response);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function* exportGenerator() {
    let count = 0;

    console.log("Executing search call first");
    yield searchMockPromise()
        .then(function* (resp) {
            yield* scrollCallback(resp);
            return resp.hits.hits;
        });

    function* scrollCallback(response) {
        console.log("Executing scroll callback");

        count += response.hits.hits.length;

        if (response.hits.total !== count) {
            console.log("Theres more data to fetch, now make a scroll call");

            yield scrollMockPromise()
                .then(function* (resp) {
                    console.log("It executed a scroll call");
                    yield* scrollCallback(resp);
                    return response.hits.hits;
                });
        }
    }
}

function init() {
    // We just want the generator to return the "response" objects from the callbacks of the Promises...
    // E.g. every part of data we get from the generator, we can inject into a streaming zip or write it somewhere.
    for (let data of exportGenerator()) {
        const promise = yield data;
        const output = yield promise;
        console.log(output);
    }
}
init();
```

Hopefully someone can point out how something like this can be achieved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this cannot be achieved. Generators and `for … of` are synchronous. Of course you can yield promises, but that doesn't buy you anything - and you'd better use `async`/`await` syntax instead.

However, you'll want to have a look at the [async iteration proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration).